combine fixtures in playwrigth
what I want
I want a way to run the test with a user logged and use that user for POM operation using fixtures.
So for Example,

First Scenario with Admin user:  I will create a {Page} and set his storageState with Admin user Info, than use this page in another fixture for POM operations
Second Scenario with Operator user:  I will create a {Page} and set his storageState with Operator user data, than use this page in another fixture for POM operations

what I did
I created a fixture that initialize a new Page and his storage for each user-
**setStorageState.fixture.ts**

type MyFixtures = {
  customer_admin_Page: Page
  customer_operator_Page: Page
}
const filePath = `${process.env.PROJECT_PATH}/temp/users/${process.env.ENV}/generated/`

import { test as base, type Page } from "@playwright/test"
export * from "@playwright/test"
export const test = base.extend<MyFixtures>({
  customer_admin_Page: async ({ browser }, use) => {
    const fileName = "rmaintainer.json"
    const context = await browser.newContext({ storageState: filePath + fileName })
    const newPage = await context.newPage()
    await use(newPage)
    await context.close()
  },
  customer_operator_Page: async ({ browser }, use) => {
    const fileName = "roperator.json"
    const context = await browser.newContext({ storageState: filePath + fileName })
    const newPage = await context.newPage()
    await use(newPage)
    await context.close()
  },
})

Than I create another fixture that follow the POM
**machinegroups.fixture.ts**

import { test as base } from "@playwright/test"
import { MachineGroups } from "/src/pom/pages/machinegroups/machinegroups.page"

export const test = base.extend<{ machineGroup: MachineGroups }>({
  //Define a fixture
  machineGroup: async ({ page }, use) => {
    const machineGroup = new MachineGroups(page)
    await use(machineGroup)
  },
})

And as Last step I want to use them in my test, where:

first I set a logged {Page}
Use the logged {Page} for POM operations;
something like this:

**addgroup.spec.ts**

import { test } from "../fixtures/machinegroups/machinegroups.fixtures"
import { test as pippo } from "../fixtures/users/local/setStorageState.fixtures"
test.describe("Admin user", () => {
  test("Admin user should add a new group", async ({ customer_admin_Page, machineGroup }) => {
    await machineGroup.clickBtnAddGroup()
  })
})

test.describe("Operator user", () => {
  test(
    "Operator user could not add a new group",
    async ({ customer_operator_Page, machineGroup }) => {
      await machineGroup.clickBtnAddGroup()
    },
  )
})

This Obviously does not work. My Idea is to find away to pass cutom_operator_page/customer_admin_Page to the page used in machineGroup fixture.
So for example, when I logged with an admin user the page in
 machineGroup: async ({ **page** }, use) => { }

will be automatically ovverided by the page from the test: for example
 machineGroup: async ({ **customer_admin_Page** }, use) => { }


Just use merge
import { mergeTests } from '@playwright/test';
import { test as dbTest } from 'database-test-utils';
import { test as a11yTest } from 'a11y-test-utils';

export const test = mergeTests(dbTest, a11yTest);

test('passes', async ({ database, page, a11y }) => {
  // use database and a11y fixtures.
});

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures#combine-custom-fixtures-from-multiple-modules

Fixtures follow these rules to determine the execution order:
When fixture A depends on fixture B: B is always set up before A and torn down after A.
Non-automatic fixtures are executed lazily, only when the test/hook needs them.
Test-scoped fixtures are torn down after each test, while worker-scoped fixtures are only torn down when the worker process executing tests is shutdown.
Execution order with fixtures
